# Minimal Blaze example in Anaconda Python

Tags: python, anaconda, blaze, datashape

I am trying to get a simple [Blaze example](http://blaze.pydata.org/docs/quickstart.html#blaze-arrays), working on Ubuntu, inside an [Anaconda installation](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) (Python 3.3).

```
import blaze
from blaze import array
from datashape import dshape

# array creation
arr1 = array(3.142)
arr2 = array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
print(arr1)
print(arr2)
```

But running gives me this error:

```
  import blaze
  File "/root/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/blaze/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import catalog
  File "/root/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/blaze/catalog/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import catalog_config
  File "/root/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/blaze/catalog/catalog_config.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .catalog_dir import is_abs_bpath, CatalogCDir
  File "/root/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/blaze/catalog/catalog_dir.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .catalog_arr import load_blaze_array
  File "/root/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/blaze/catalog/catalog_arr.py", line 9, in <module>
    from datashape.type_equation_solver import matches_datashape_pattern
ImportError: No module named 'datashape.type_equation_solver'
```

However, I am able to import `datashape`, using

```
python -c "import datashape"
```

And when I try to `conda install <pkgname>`, I get that the dependencies are satisfied. I think that this is related to [this question](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/blaze-dev/saWhZwBevQU), but I find that advice impenetrable.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particular error you're getting looks like it's from blaze being built from a more recent checkout than datashape. If you update both of them to the latest master from github, the blaze import should work.

Comment: This seems plausible. I will try this and get back.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there's no file or directory named `blaze` under your current working directory.